# the correct way to apply permissions to a registry key REG_SZ

Tags: windows-7, batch, cmd.exe

With [regini](http://ss64.com/nt/regini.html), usually following is used to set permissions reg key.

```
regdemo.txt
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows [1 9]
```

But, i need to know what is the correct way to apply permissions to a REG_SZ, DWORD, etc

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows 
"Value"=dword:0000000 [1 9]
"Value"="Data" [1 7]
```

Example of Content of regdemo.txt is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
"Value"="Data" [1 17]
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows "Value"="Data" [1 17]
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Value Data [1 17]
```

Or another I do not know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registry Values inside Keys don't support permissions, so there's no way to apply permissions directly to the Values.  It must be controlled at the parent Key.

To illustrate (using RegEdit), permissions on a Key:

[image]

Now, try it on a value:

[image]

Notice there's no "Permissions" choice.

Comment: it is only an example. please. i change the example key now

Comment: sorry. you are right